# Creating Entity Data Model from Oracle database using ODP.NET

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net, odac

Problem: The Oracle data source I've created in the Server Explorer that uses ODP.NET is not showing up in the Entity Data Model Wizard to create an *.edmx

The following walkthrough is what I've attempted to follow but when I get to step 4 of "Creating an Entity Data Model using the Entity Data Model Wizard", the connection I've created does not show up in the dropdown. Also, ODP.NET does not exist as a possible data provider when trying to create a new connection.

http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm

I've successfully done this many times over with SQL Server. The weird thing is, ODP.NET is listed as a data provider when creating new connections in the Server Explorer.

What I have:
- Win7
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- .Net framework 4
- Entity Framework 4
- 64 Bit ODAC 11.2.0.3

Any help would be awesome!!

Comment: I downloaded and installed the 32bit version of ODAC 11.2.0.3 and it works now...
I am using .Net 3.5 though :( . Our server isn't supporting 4 yet.

All that's left is to implement my generic repository pattern to see if all this effort has paid off!!